# mongodb sharding issue with 2.5.5 development version

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I am trying to perform performance testing for one of my application using MongoDB. I am using 2.5.5 development version. Sharding works fine when I try to read and write data using mongos.

To perform performance testing I need to start 600-700 mongoconnection threads to the mongos. Each thread queries around 2000 documents which is distributed on two shards. This test runs fine for few minutes but after sometime it stops working with the error "Connection refused by one of the shard". Looking closely at it I found that server runs out of ports when these many threads request data.

Could anyone please have a look and let me know if it is a MongoDB bug in the dev version or is it something which I am doing wrong while connecting to database.

your help will be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Vibhu

Comment: Can you paste application code? Which server is running out of ports? A bit about your environment will be useful to know if it is specific to OS resource setting. I would suggest looking at the MongoDB production notes.

Comment: Shard server is running out of ports. I have increased the port number to max for all the servers i.e. config and shard servers. but this is also not working. My MongoDB resides on Ubuntu.

Comment: Can you do "sudo lsof" when the server runs out of connections and why are so many clients connected? If you 600-700  threads, at max i would assume it should have been only that many connections. Ideally it would be lot lesser. The reason i want to look at application code is to make sure you are not leaking connections. lsof command should help identifying that.. As well as connection count in the mongod  / mongos logs.